# interpretation of cluster_centers_ in Kmeans clustering

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, tf-idf

I have developed the Kmeans model and below is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
import pandas as pd

documents = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
             "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
             "The EPS user interface management system",
             "System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
             "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
             "The generation of random binary unordered trees",
             "The intersection graph of paths in trees",
             "Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
             "Graph minors A survey"]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',max_features= 10)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
true_k = 2
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
```

The vocab list is:

```
vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
array(['computer', 'eps', 'graph', 'human', 'interface', 'minors',
       'survey', 'time', 'trees', 'user'], dtype=object)
```

and coordinates for cluster centroids are:

```
print (model.cluster_centers_)

[[0.21866736 0.26189498 0.         0.25689141 0.23594367 0.
  0.10319731 0.25412544 0.         0.32570307]
 [0.         0.         0.4448599  0.         0.         0.30832905
  0.15059203 0.         0.56392448 0.        ]]
```

For getting top n words in each cluster:

```
print (model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1])

[[9 1 3 7 4 0 6 8 5 2]
 [8 2 5 6 9 7 4 3 1 0]]
```

My question is why we use `.argsort()[:, ::-1]` not only `.argsort()` as we want the indice of words having shortest distance from centroid and `argsort` defaults to ascending?

For example: in given array, `[9 1 3 7 4 0 6 8 5 2]` the index 9 (`word: user`) and (`coordinate value: 0.32570307`) is farthest from centroid while index 2 (`word: graph`) and (`coordinate value: 0`) is closest to centroid. So, actual format should be `[2 5 8 6 0 4 7 3 1 9]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting `model.cluster_centers_`. These values are not the distances but the tf-idf values.

After clustering, the centroid represents the mean tf-idf value for each word per cluster. The higher the tf-idf value, the more important a word is for that cluster.

You sort from larger to smaller by using `argsort()[:, ::-1]`.